# Adding a Back to Top web part

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

Is it possible to create a web part that publishing page editors can insert and all it contains is an anchor tag to take the user "Back to Top" of the page?

I've added this to the top of the pages' HTML:

```
<a id="top">
```

Then, I'd like non-HTML coders to be able to add this anywhere they'd like on SharePoint 2010 publishing pages:

```
<a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `id="Top"` instead of `name="Top"`

It should be rather easy.
Insert a HTMLform webpart and insert your `<a href="top">Go to top</a>`, save it and export the webpart and call it "BackToTopWP". Then you can import it and it should be available for all admins/moderators/whatever to insert.

Comment: Thanks, Dandroid; correction has been made. Any way to add this as a web part for editors to insert into pages.

Comment: @AlexC Please view my edit :)

Comment: One other thought: Can this be automated? In other words, can jQuery parse a particular area of the page layout on the pub page and auto insert this link after every web part/paragraph of text? Just a thought. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @AlexC Indeed it can. If it is supposed to be placed within webparts, you can make jQuery insert this very link into them as all webparts have the same HTML structure untill you hit the `ms-WPBody` div. The jQuery would look something like this: `$('.ms-wpTopTable .ms-WPBody p').append('<a href="#top">Go to top</a>');`

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint pages already include a #mainContent anchor that you could reuse:

```
<a href="#mainContent">Back to Top</a>
```

I think it is also associated with the accesskey J.